# How one can find and edit SMF forum websites from hosting cpanel?

Tags: php, smf-forum

My boss asked me to add a CAPTCHA code to the question submission page in his website which he says has designed using SMF forums and it's obvious that it's a forum site.

Now when I went to cPanel hosting where all the site files exist, I see no HTML code in any `.php` files.

And mainly, after staring for like 7 hours, I didn't understand any of that PHP code.

The site is www.usmlemed.com.

Example index file code as:

```
$forum_version = 'SMF 2.0.13';
@ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

// Get everything started up...
define('SMF', 1);
if (function_exists('set_magic_quotes_runtime'))
    @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
error_reporting(defined('E_STRICT') ? E_ALL | E_STRICT : E_ALL);
$time_start = microtime();

// This makes it so headers can be sent!
ob_start();

// Do some cleaning, just in case.
foreach (array('db_character_set', 'cachedir') as $variable)
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$variable]))
        unset($GLOBALS[$variable], $GLOBALS[$variable]);

// Load the settings...
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Settings.php');

// Make absolutely sure the cache directory is defined.
if ((empty($cachedir) || !file_exists($cachedir)) && file_exists($boarddir . '/cache'))
    $cachedir = $boarddir . '/cache';

// And important includes.
require_once($sourcedir . '/QueryString.php');
require_once($sourcedir . '/Subs.php');
require_once($sourcedir . '/Errors.php');
require_once($sourcedir . '/Load.php');
require_once($sourcedir . '/Security.php');

// Using an pre-PHP 5.1 version?
if (@version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1') == -1)
    require_once($sourcedir . '/Subs-Compat.php');

// If $maintenance is set specifically to 2, then we're upgrading or something.
if (!empty($maintenance) && $maintenance == 2)
    db_fatal_error();

// Create a variable to store some SMF specific functions in.
$smcFunc = array();

// Initate the database connection and define some database functions to use.
loadDatabase();

// Load the settings from the settings table, and perform operations like optimizing.
reloadSettings();
// Clean the request variables, add slashes, etc.
cleanRequest();
$context = array();

// Seed the random generator.
if (empty($modSettings['rand_seed']) || mt_rand(1, 250) == 69)
    smf_seed_generator();

// Before we get carried away, are we doing a scheduled task? If so save CPU cycles by jumping out!
if (isset($_GET['scheduled']))
{
    require_once($sourcedir . '/ScheduledTasks.php');
    AutoTask();
}

// Check if compressed output is enabled, supported, and not already being done.
if (!empty($modSettings['enableCompressedOutput']) && !headers_sent())
{
    // If zlib is being used, turn off output compression.
    if (@ini_get('zlib.output_compression') == '1' || @ini_get('output_handler') == 'ob_gzhandler' || @version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '4.2.0') == -1)
        $modSettings['enableCompressedOutput'] = '0';
    else
    {
        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    }
}

// Emit some headers for some modicum of protection against nasties.
if (!headers_sent())
{
    // Future versions will make some of this configurable. This is primarily a 'safe' configuration for most cases for now.
    header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
    header('X-XSS-Protection: 1');
    header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
}

// Register an error handler.
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Start the session. (assuming it hasn't already been.)
loadSession();

// Determine if this is using WAP, WAP2, or imode.  Technically, we should check that wap comes before application/xhtml or text/html, but this doesn't work in practice as much as it should.
if (isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode']))
    unset($_SESSION['nowap']);
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['nowap']))
    $_SESSION['nowap'] = true;
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['nowap']))
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') !== false)
        $_REQUEST['wap2'] = 1;
    elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'text/vnd.wap.wml') !== false)
    {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'DoCoMo/') !== false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'portalmmm/') !== false)
            $_REQUEST['imode'] = 1;
        else
            $_REQUEST['wap'] = 1;
    }
}

if (!defined('WIRELESS'))
    define('WIRELESS', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode']));

// Some settings and headers are different for wireless protocols.
if (WIRELESS)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) ? 'wap' : (isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ? 'wap2' : (isset($_REQUEST['imode']) ? 'imode' : '')));

    // Some cellphones can't handle output compression...
    $modSettings['enableCompressedOutput'] = '0';
    // !!! Do we want these hard coded?
    $modSettings['defaultMaxMessages'] = 5;
    $modSettings['defaultMaxTopics'] = 9;

    // Wireless protocol header.
    if (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap')
        header('Content-Type: text/vnd.wap.wml');
}

// Restore post data if we are revalidating OpenID.
if (isset($_GET['openid_restore_post']) && !empty($_SESSION['openid']['saved_data'][$_GET['openid_restore_post']]['post']) && empty($_POST))
{
    $_POST = $_SESSION['openid']['saved_data'][$_GET['openid_restore_post']]['post'];
    unset($_SESSION['openid']['saved_data'][$_GET['openid_restore_post']]);
}

// What function shall we execute? (done like this for memory's sake.)
call_user_func(smf_main());

// Call obExit specially; we're coming from the main area ;).
obExit(null, null, true);

// The main controlling function.
function smf_main()
{
    global $modSettings, $settings, $user_info, $board, $topic, $board_info, $maintenance, $sourcedir;

    // Special case: session keep-alive, output a transparent pixel.
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'keepalive')
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        die("\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\xF9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x2C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x44\x01\x00\x3B");
    }

    // Load the user's cookie (or set as guest) and load their settings.
    loadUserSettings();

    // Load the current board's information.
    loadBoard();

    // Load the current user's permissions.
    loadPermissions();

    // Attachments don't require the entire theme to be loaded.
    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'dlattach' && (!empty($modSettings['allow_guestAccess']) && $user_info['is_guest']))
        detectBrowser();
    // Load the current theme.  (note that ?theme=1 will also work, may be used for guest theming.)
    else
        loadTheme();

    // Check if the user should be disallowed access.
    is_not_banned();

    // If we are in a topic and don't have permission to approve it then duck out now.
    if (!empty($topic) && empty($board_info['cur_topic_approved']) && !allowedTo('approve_posts') && ($user_info['id'] != $board_info['cur_topic_starter'] || $user_info['is_guest']))
        fatal_lang_error('not_a_topic', false);

    // Do some logging, unless this is an attachment, avatar, toggle of editor buttons, theme option, XML feed etc.
    if (empty($_REQUEST['action']) || !in_array($_REQUEST['action'], array('dlattach', 'findmember', 'jseditor', 'jsoption', 'requestmembers', 'smstats', '.xml', 'xmlhttp', 'verificationcode', 'viewquery', 'viewsmfile')))
    {
        // Log this user as online.
        writeLog();

        // Track forum statistics and hits...?
        if (!empty($modSettings['hitStats']))
            trackStats(array('hits' => '+'));
    }

    // Is the forum in maintenance mode? (doesn't apply to administrators.)
    if (!empty($maintenance) && !allowedTo('admin_forum'))
    {
        // You can only login.... otherwise, you're getting the "maintenance mode" display.
        if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'login2' || $_REQUEST['action'] == 'logout'))
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/LogInOut.php');
            return $_REQUEST['action'] == 'login2' ? 'Login2' : 'Logout';
        }
        // Don't even try it, sonny.
        else
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/Subs-Auth.php');
            return 'InMaintenance';
        }
    }
    // If guest access is off, a guest can only do one of the very few following actions.
    elseif (empty($modSettings['allow_guestAccess']) && $user_info['is_guest'] && (!isset($_REQUEST['action']) || !in_array($_REQUEST['action'], array('coppa', 'login', 'login2', 'register', 'register2', 'reminder', 'activate', 'help', 'smstats', 'mailq', 'verificationcode', 'openidreturn'))))
    {
        require_once($sourcedir . '/Subs-Auth.php');
        return 'KickGuest';
    }
    elseif (empty($_REQUEST['action']))
    {
        // Action and board are both empty... BoardIndex!
        if (empty($board) && empty($topic))
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/BoardIndex.php');
            return 'BoardIndex';
        }
        // Topic is empty, and action is empty.... MessageIndex!
        elseif (empty($topic))
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/MessageIndex.php');
            return 'MessageIndex';
        }
        // Board is not empty... topic is not empty... action is empty.. Display!
        else
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/Display.php');
            return 'Display';
        }
    }

    // Here's the monstrous $_REQUEST['action'] array - $_REQUEST['action'] => array($file, $function).
    $actionArray = array(
        'activate' => array('Register.php', 'Activate'),
        'admin' => array('Admin.php', 'AdminMain'),
        'announce' => array('Post.php', 'AnnounceTopic'),
        'attachapprove' => array('ManageAttachments.php', 'ApproveAttach'),
        'buddy' => array('Subs-Members.php', 'BuddyListToggle'),
        'calendar' => array('Calendar.php', 'CalendarMain'),
        'clock' => array('Calendar.php', 'clock'),
        'collapse' => array('BoardIndex.php', 'CollapseCategory'),
        'coppa' => array('Register.php', 'CoppaForm'),
        'credits' => array('Who.php', 'Credits'),
        'deletemsg' => array('RemoveTopic.php', 'DeleteMessage'),
        'display' => array('Display.php', 'Display'),
        'dlattach' => array('Display.php', 'Download'),
        'editpoll' => array('Poll.php', 'EditPoll'),
        'editpoll2' => array('Poll.php', 'EditPoll2'),
        'emailuser' => array('SendTopic.php', 'EmailUser'),
        'findmember' => array('Subs-Auth.php', 'JSMembers'),
        'groups' => array('Groups.php', 'Groups'),
        'help' => array('Help.php', 'ShowHelp'),
        'helpadmin' => array('Help.php', 'ShowAdminHelp'),
        'im' => array('PersonalMessage.php', 'MessageMain'),
        'jseditor' => array('Subs-Editor.php', 'EditorMain'),
        'jsmodify' => array('Post.php', 'JavaScriptModify'),
        'jsoption' => array('Themes.php', 'SetJavaScript'),
        'lock' => array('LockTopic.php', 'LockTopic'),
        'lockvoting' => array('Poll.php', 'LockVoting'),
        'login' => array('LogInOut.php', 'Login'),
        'login2' => array('LogInOut.php', 'Login2'),
        'logout' => array('LogInOut.php', 'Logout'),
        'markasread' => array('Subs-Boards.php', 'MarkRead'),
        'mergetopics' => array('SplitTopics.php', 'MergeTopics'),
        'mlist' => array('Memberlist.php', 'Memberlist'),
        'moderate' => array('ModerationCenter.php', 'ModerationMain'),
        'modifycat' => array('ManageBoards.php', 'ModifyCat'),
        'modifykarma' => array('Karma.php', 'ModifyKarma'),
        'movetopic' => array('MoveTopic.php', 'MoveTopic'),
        'movetopic2' => array('MoveTopic.php', 'MoveTopic2'),
        'notify' => array('Notify.php', 'Notify'),
        'notifyboard' => array('Notify.php', 'BoardNotify'),
        'openidreturn' => array('Subs-OpenID.php', 'smf_openID_return'),
        'pm' => array('PersonalMessage.php', 'MessageMain'),
        'post' => array('Post.php', 'Post'),
        'post2' => array('Post.php', 'Post2'),
        'printpage' => array('Printpage.php', 'PrintTopic'),
        'profile' => array('Profile.php', 'ModifyProfile'),
        'quotefast' => array('Post.php', 'QuoteFast'),
        'quickmod' => array('MessageIndex.php', 'QuickModeration'),
        'quickmod2' => array('Display.php', 'QuickInTopicModeration'),
        'recent' => array('Recent.php', 'RecentPosts'),
        'register' => array('Register.php', 'Register'),
        'register2' => array('Register.php', 'Register2'),
        'reminder' => array('Reminder.php', 'RemindMe'),
        'removepoll' => array('Poll.php', 'RemovePoll'),
        'removetopic2' => array('RemoveTopic.php', 'RemoveTopic2'),
        'reporttm' => array('SendTopic.php', 'ReportToModerator'),
        'requestmembers' => array('Subs-Auth.php', 'RequestMembers'),
        'restoretopic' => array('RemoveTopic.php', 'RestoreTopic'),
        'search' => array('Search.php', 'PlushSearch1'),
        'search2' => array('Search.php', 'PlushSearch2'),
        'sendtopic' => array('SendTopic.php', 'EmailUser'),
        'smstats' => array('Stats.php', 'SMStats'),
        'suggest' => array('Subs-Editor.php', 'AutoSuggestHandler'),
        'spellcheck' => array('Subs-Post.php', 'SpellCheck'),
        'splittopics' => array('SplitTopics.php', 'SplitTopics'),
        'stats' => array('Stats.php', 'DisplayStats'),
        'sticky' => array('LockTopic.php', 'Sticky'),
        'theme' => array('Themes.php', 'ThemesMain'),
        'trackip' => array('Profile-View.php', 'trackIP'),
        'about:mozilla' => array('Karma.php', 'BookOfUnknown'),
        'about:unknown' => array('Karma.php', 'BookOfUnknown'),
        'unread' => array('Recent.php', 'UnreadTopics'),
        'unreadreplies' => array('Recent.php', 'UnreadTopics'),
        'verificationcode' => array('Register.php', 'VerificationCode'),
        'viewprofile' => array('Profile.php', 'ModifyProfile'),
        'vote' => array('Poll.php', 'Vote'),
        'viewquery' => array('ViewQuery.php', 'ViewQuery'),
        'viewsmfile' => array('Admin.php', 'DisplayAdminFile'),
        'who' => array('Who.php', 'Who'),
        '.xml' => array('News.php', 'ShowXmlFeed'),
        'xmlhttp' => array('Xml.php', 'XMLhttpMain'),
    );

    // Allow modifying $actionArray easily.
    call_integration_hook('integrate_actions', array(&$actionArray));

    // Get the function and file to include - if it's not there, do the board index.
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['action']) || !isset($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']]))
    {
        // Catch the action with the theme?
        if (!empty($settings['catch_action']))
        {
            require_once($sourcedir . '/Themes.php');
            return 'WrapAction';
        }

        // Fall through to the board index then...
        require_once($sourcedir . '/BoardIndex.php');
        return 'BoardIndex';
    }

    // Otherwise, it was set - so let's go to that action.
    require_once($sourcedir . '/' . $actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][0]);
    return $actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the HTML is being generated *by* the PHP scripts. You can echo html out onto the form, and it'll appear to the user as regular HTML.

Find where the php actually outputs a page to the user and you'll see hopefully where to include the captcha. You'll need to make sure that it's added to a `<form>` tag, and that the right `siteid` is passed to the form it's submitted to.

EDIT: It's in `actionArray`. `smf_main` grabs from a bunch of other data sources. Dig into those files until you find the one that's actually outputting the form data to the page.